# How do I get drag and drop to not break links?

Tags: unity

Using Unity 2022.3.1f1 (LTS). Several sources have indicated that you can drag and drop items within the assets or hierarchy without breaking links, but when I do it, it seems to be treating it as if I deleted the file, and then pasted a new copy in the new place. For example, I had physics materials on some colliders, and decided to do some tidying up, so I created a subfolder for physics materials and dragged them into the folder. All of the colliders now have broken links indicating that the material they were referencing no longer exists, and I get a handful of warnings in the console about there being a meta file (in the old location) that exists, but that the object it references can't be found.

Comment: Just to make to sure, you are doing drag and drop within unity and not over some file manager, right?

Comment: Seconding what Zibelas says, this sounds like the symptoms you get if you use your OS file manager (like Explorer on Windows / Finder on Mac) and drag only the asset files to a new folder, leaving their corresponding .meta files behind. When you do this drag and drop fully inside the Unity editor's Project tab, it automatically moves these two files together as a unit. Can you update your question to show/describe exactly what you're dragging, in what window(s)?

Comment: Yes, this is all within Unity, moving items inside the asset tab by clicking on them and dragging within the same tab.

Comment: Very strange, I've never seen that. I'd report a bug to the development team, and try a fresh re-install of the engine. Do you have any custom importers or other customizations in your project that could potentially be interfering here? Or version control that's trying to put the .meta files back in the old folder after Unity moved them?